# Web pages don't show correctly on chrome mobile(Android)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I have faced a weird problem recently when I checked my website with my mobile on chrome I saw that It is not showing the right things

some colors were different, tables and generally it wasn't what I was expecting

It is totally different with the desktop

To understand what I mean check http://yking.ir

One time with your pc and with your phone

does anyone know what is the problem

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3.7 in my design and my server-side is PHP

Update

I finally found out the problem

My mobile chrome browser had cached the site and After I cleared the cache it fixed.

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my html browser on the phone show the page correctly but the google chrome isn't show the page in the right way.

Comment: You read that guide really fast.

Comment: May be your media query went wrong or it has any other values, please check in your css file.

Comment: I checked the media query, There isn't any problem with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out the problem

My mobile chrome browser had cached the site and After I cleared the cache it fixed.